# Outlook Addin Error Installation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, outlook-addin

Hi guys ive published my addin using clickonce. Its working fine on some computers but on others it got an error of this:

[image]

Things ive tried(according to my searches):

- Unblocked the zip file, then proceed to the installation
- Creating Certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Folder in digital signatures.
- Unchecked the "Sign the ClickOnce manifest" in the projects properties

Note: The setup is in the C drive in the users local computer.

Still no good, any idea on what the problem might be??

thanks in advance
have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Did you purchase the certificate from trusted vendor (CA)? Or did you use a test certificate for signing the soltion?

See [How to: Add a Trusted Publisher to a Client Computer for ClickOnce Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172241.aspx) for more information.

The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx) article describes all the required steps for deploying Office solutions.

Comment: Hi, i didnt purchase any certificate and i unchecked the "Sign the ClickOnce manifest", and i already followed the deployment process on that link, as i said in my question, its working fine on some computers but not on the others. Thank you